# Check if certain value exists is any 4 out of 10 columns

Tags: sql, informatica

I wish to check if value 'true' exists in any 4 of the 10 columns. It can be done using simple if else but is there any specific efficient way so that I don't miss out any combination without using loop.
Set output 'yes' if any 4 columns for each row is true.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Seems simple enough. Write some SQL and show us how far you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I like to do.  Whether it is proper or not is another story.

I convert my `BIT` columns into `INT` and add them... true converts to 1 and false converts to 0.

```
SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN CAST(BitCol1 AS INT) + 
           CAST(BitCol2 AS INT) +
           CAST(BitCol3 AS INT) +
           CAST(BitCol4 AS INT) +
           CAST(BitCol5 AS INT) +
           CAST(BitCol6 AS INT) + 
           CAST(BitCol7 AS INT) + 
           CAST(BitCol8 AS INT) + 
           CAST(BitCol9 AS INT) +
           CAST(BitCol10 AS INT) >= 4
      THEN 'Yes'
      ELSE 'No'
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you your desired result:

```
SELECT IF(count(id) >= 4, 'YES', 'NO') AS OUTPUT
FROM TABLE_NAME    
WHERE 'true' in (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, ..., COLUMN10);
```

Replace `TABLE_NAME` with your table and `COLUMN` with your table columns.